# Cloud-ml unable to deploy model with tables_initializer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I am looking to deploy a trained model to ml-engine. I can locally run my code with something like:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
  example_result = sess.run(
                    my_model, 
                    feed_dict=###snip###
                  )
```

I have been trying to export with:

```
export_builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess, 
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], 
        signature_def_map={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: sig
        })
```

which I can then deploy to ml-engine. However, when I call the model I get an error as the tables are not initialised.

**How can I deploy a model where the tables are initialized automatically/by default?**

---

**Things I have tried:**

1. Adding the `tf.tables_initializer()` as a dependency before any of the ops in `my_model`

This works for the *first* time I call my deployed model but fails every subsequent call with an error message telling me the table is already initialized

2. Passing the `tf.tables_initializer()` as the `legacy_init_op` parameter to the `add_meta_graph_and_variables` method.

this fails to deploy to ml-engine at all with the error message

> Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load
>   model: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (Error code: 0)"

3. Passing the `tf.tables_initializer()` or `tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op()` as the `main_op` parameter to the `add_meta_graph_and_variables` method.

In each case, it still fails to deploy the model with the same error message as in (2.):

> Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load
>   model: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (Error code: 0)"

Comment: I think there's a problem with the error reporting here. Do you mind sending your project + model + version information to cloudml-feedback@google.com and reference this thread so we can dig deeper?

Comment: @rhaertel80 thanks for looking into it - I have emailed the details

Comment: @rhaertel80 Any further news? Is there anything I can do to get this deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must pass the tables initializer op as the `main_op` but also, crucially, we need to include the `assets_collection` in our call to `add_meta_graph_and_variables`:

```
init_op = tf.tables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), init_op])
  example_result = sess.run(
                my_model, 
                feed_dict=###snip###
              )
```

then

```
    export_builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess, 
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        main_op = init_op,
        assets_collection=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.ASSET_FILEPATHS),
        signature_def_map={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: sig
        }
    )
```

---

As an (arguably simpler) alternative, we could use the [`simple_save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/simple_save) method to save our model

Comment: Many thanks to the support team at cloudml-feedback@google.com for providing this answer in response to the support request raised through @rhaertel80 (posted here at their request)

Comment: What will be happened if not adding `assets_collection `?